# How to add content assist for css, html.. in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, content-assist

Are there any libraries that we can add to Elipse to support context assist (css, html) like Netbean?
Many thanks,

[image: CSS content assist is included Netbean]

Comment: Eclipse already comes with excellent content assist support for both HTML and CSS as well. Are you not able to view the content assist ? Have you tried hitting CTRL+SPACE while typing ?

Comment: CTRL + SPACE in eclipse doesn't show content support for css code. Example: I type: border => it shows list of tag has name started with border, but it doesn't show content assist for border

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which Eclipse package you installed you may already have the CSS and HTML editors. If you don't then you can install them using `Help > Install New Software`. Choose the software site for your version of Eclipse in the drop down list and look at the `Web, XML, Jave EE and OSGi Enterprise Development` section. The `Eclipse Web Developer Tools` section contains the editors you want but the other sections may also be of interest.

Answer (score -1):

You can look at some plug-ins (http://marketplace.eclipse.org) providing support for editing HTML and CSS files.

Search in Editor category.